# Want to build & install Glibc in Android (bionic)

Tags: android, linux, open-source, glibc, termux

But i am getting error..

My configure option was

```
../configure CFLAGS="-march=native -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -pipe" --prefix=$PREFIX --libdir=$PREFIX/lib --libexecdir=$PREFIX/lib --with-headers=$PREFIX/include --enable-bind-now --enable-cet --enable-kernel=5.10 --enable-stack-protector=strong --disable-profile --disable-crypt --disable-werror --enable-systemtap --target=aarch64-linux-android --host=aarch64-linux-android
```

I am trying to compile glibc for Android (bionic) base Termux ..

Compiling with `gcc` but depending on bionic

`aarch64-linux-android`

My host processor aarch64
My target processor aarch64
My host platform Android 12 (termux)
My target platform Android 12 (termux)

I want to build & install in termux..
And termux not depending on aarch64-linux-gnu..
Termux depends on aarch64-linux-android

mey be it is not possible.. but i am trying to do it for experimental purpose..

I have all dependency package installed like gcc, clang, python etc..

Somewhere i found glibc for termux..
But it is not depending on `aarch64-linux-android`

I know developer can do anything..
I don't know any computer language so i want help..

My error log

```
In file included from <command-line>:
syslog.c: In function '__vsyslog_internal':
syslog.c:94:30: error: inlining failed in call to 'always_inline' 'syslog': function not inlinable
```

Somehow i removed a single line `134` from `syslog.c` solved this issue..

But after last position i received too many undefined reference to error..

https://pastebin.com/U8NcNf97

Don't know how do I solve..
Thank you..

Comment: We need to see the whole error message. The function `syslog` was declared with the `always_inline` attribute but the compiler couldn't inline it. What _file_ and what line number caused the error. Please _edit_ your _question_ and provide the additional information. You might even include a snippet of the offending lines as well.

Comment: I think you have a forked/non-standard glibc source tree. I have the glibc source from the official git repo and it does _not_ mark `__vsyslog_internal` as `always_inline`. Please _edit_ your _question_ and describe your development system and target system. (e.g.) "My development system is an x86_64 PC running linux, ubuntu version X and my target platform is a Raspberry PI 4 running ubuntu version Y". A brief search indicates `termux` is something you install directly on android? Normally, android development is done on an ubuntu/linux PC with "android studio"--it allows cross-devel easily

Comment: Actually i am clone from https://github.com/bminor/glibc here..  my processor aarch64 and i am useing termux.. without proot..

Comment: Actually your targeted system is linux and host system also linux.. but my targeted system is Android host system also Android.. i am compiling with `aarch64-linux-android`... Can it possible to compile with Android ndk ? If yes then with termux also possible..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't want to offend you, but you are essentially wasting your time trying to compile `glibc` with `bionic` compilers. To compile `glibc`, you need `glibc` (i.e. glibc-based compiler and dependencies) - this is the most correct approach. It may be possible to compile `glibc` with `bionic`, but the setup process will be terribly complicated and time consuming (plus, it will be a completely different library, in effect).

Also, I want to say that you configured `PREFIX` incorrectly in `configure`. It's better to separate `glibc` and all its bases from the bionic-based termux system, then you risk breaking termux. In addition to properly configuring `configure`, one should remove running unsupported **system calls** in `glibc` source files, this is important as such **system calls** can cause a `Bad system call` error when starting any glibc-based program.

For understanding, I have experience compiling `glibc` for termux - https://github.com/Maxython/glibc-for-termux.

Comment: Thank you for response.. I am HappY from your channel.. i understood and also leave..